# Mathematical foundations of formal semantics in linguistic

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for information on the mathematical foundations of formal semantics in linguistic. After some time, I found this book (Mathematical methods in linguistics / by Barbara H. Partee, Alice ter Meulen and Robert E. Wall) which is no accessible for me. My problem is that I do not know exactly what I am looking for, as I am missing the right keywords when searching.

I am interested in:

- Set theory/ first order logic as a basis for formal semantics or formal linguistic in general
- Type theory as a basis for it
- (Dis-)Advantages of one or the other

Thank you very much for any advice where to look, a short outline or references.

Comment: I suspect you will get better answers on linguistics.stackexchange.com, but it's also on topic here. Good luck!